# SQL - How to select a user based on wether or not that user exists in a different table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been having some trouble with an SQL statement I'm trying to create and I figured that someone here would probably be able to help me out.

I've got two tables: Matches and Users.
The Matches table consists of User_id and Partner_id that represents a user and their respective match (partner).
Each time a user clicks a button, a new match will be found and a row will be created in the Matches table.

Now, when a user clicks the button to find a match, I need to - randomly - find a user in the Users table that is not the user himself (obviously) and does not already have a relation to the current user in the Matches table. - This is where I get stuck.

How can I pick a user based on the criteria that they do not already have a relation to the currently logged in user, through the Matches table?

All answers are much appreciated. Thank you.

Edit: Having read both [SQL - find records from one table which don't exist in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367863/sql-find-records-from-one-table-which-dont-exist-in-another) and [Sql select row if no row exists in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26262994/sql-select-row-if-no-row-exists-in-other-table) (as well as others)  only had me more confused afterwards. - I simply didn't quite understand the answers that were given well enough to convert them to what would have been useful in my case.

Comment: Your question is not very clear... No code either.. Your context is not only SQL, but application + db. What do you mean by " a user that  has not already been matched with the user." ?

Comment: @RémiBecheras I apologize that you feel I was not clear enough. I was trying not to complicate something otherwise quite simple, as to avoid any misunderstandings regarding what I was attempting. - I will keep the simplicity of the question, but I will edit it to include a better explanation of the line you are questioning. - What do you mean by this being application + DB, though? Though I do plan to use it in my application, this is only a question about the SQL. - Mind explaining what you meant?

Comment: @kordirko I partially agree that it's a duplicate. I had already read the one you linked, as well as several others, but did not feel that I had gotten my answer. - Probably because I'm still quite new to this and I was unable to alter the given answers in the other threads, to solve the problem I was facing. Thank you for notifying me about it, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
    user_id
from
    users u
where
    user_id<>$own_id
    and not exists (
      select * from matches m
      where
          m.user_id=u.user_id
          or m.partner_id=u.user_id
    )
order by rand()
limit 1
```

Although note that `order by rand()` is not the most efficient solution. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823306/mysql-alternatives-to-order-by-rand) and consider some alternatives.